# Rapid-Fail Worker Processes

Tags: iis, worker-process

in ISS my application pool is shutdown due to Rapid-Fail Protection for Worker Processes
now how can i identify that why Worker Process fails??
I looked into log but couldn't find some thing informational. It only gives error

---

```
Event Type:        Error
Event Source:    W3SVC
Event Category:                None
Event ID:              1002
Date:                     1/23/2012
Time:                     3:29:49 PM
User:                     N/A
Computer:          BA5SWWW006
```

**Description:**

```
Application pool 'apppool_name' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Well, your worker process is crashing way too many times than it should. The default value is 5 crashes in 5 minutes, and your pool will be disabled.

Now, as you can see... you shouldn't be trying to fix Rapid Fail protection. Concentrate more on how to fix the crash. This blog here, might help you.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2006/03/02/what-is-a-crash-technically-in-asp-net-and-what-to-do-if-it-happens.aspx